# Relational Algebra: How can i find a dancer who has done two or more dancers called 'tango'

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-algebra

- Dancer (dancerCode, dancerName, dancerSex, dancerAge)
- Performance (performCode, dancerCode, date, time, performType)

  Find the dancers name who have performed two or more tango dances. 
  I cant work out how this can be done without a count.

Comment: Start by joining Performance to itself on the dancerCode

Answer (score 0):

You could use correlated subqueries

```
select d.dancerName
from Dancer d, Performance p
where p.dancerCode = d.dancerCode and p.performType = 'Tango' and
      exists (select *
              from Performance p2
              where p2.dancerCode = d.dancerCode
                    and p2.performType = 'Tango'
                    and p2.performCode <> p.performCode)
```